# dealing with tictactoe detecting the buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

So, I'm working on a project that uses a `GridLayout` and an array of `tictactoetile`, which is a class which extends `JButton`.
For an example of the first thing I'm trying to do, I want to find out what button is clicked, and then set that button's text to equal either x or o depending on which turn it is. I have the logic for that down, I just don't know how to get the row and column of the button clicked.
Sorry if this is not worded well.

Comment: Could you store the co-ordinates as fields of `TicTacToeTile`?

Comment: Assuming you're using a `ActionListener`, you would already have access to the `source` that generated the event...

Comment: I assume you mean evt.getsource(), which is what I wanted to use but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class tictactoetile extends JButton implements ActionListener {

     private int cory;
     private int corx;
     //Create your own GameObj class with the necessary members
     //Some examples for members below...
     private GameObj game;

     public tictactoetile(int x,int y,GameObj gam) {
         cory = y;
         corx = x;
         game = gam;
         super();
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         this.setText(game.getTurnMarker()); //returns either x or o
         game.updateGameState(game.getTurn(),cory,corx);
         game.nextTurn();
     }
}
```